# Increment an array in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, tasm

Coding an assembly program to be used as a dictionary. User gives in the word and the program checks whether that word is present or not. TASM, 16 bit. Program works perfect for the first two elements of the array but if I provide `balls.` , the 3rd element of the array, even though the next element of array is being chosen, (verified on `emu8086`, `bx` becomes  `007ch`,->refer to code<-), the `repe cmpsb` still finishes its check after a single try. **works properly with the first two elements of the array**. Here is my code
The program firsts checks the length and later the bits. Length check is ended when a period (**.**) is provided.

```
.model large
.data
arrayele db 00d ;to count if all elements of the array have been compared with
count db 00d ;length of input count
nl db 10d,13d,'$' ;newline
mne db "Not Equal$" ;message if not equal
me db "Equal$" ;message if equal
buf db 99,?,99 dup(?) ;buffer where the input will be saved
w0 db "hello$" ;word 0-5
w1 db "which$"
w2 db "balls$"
w3 db "table$"
w4 db "chair$"
w5 db "apples$"
words dw offset w0,offset w1 ;the array
      dw offset w2,offset w3
      dw offset w4,offset w5
.code

main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax

    ;take user input
    mov ah,0ah
    mov dx,offset buf
    int 21h

    ;print new line
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset nl
    int 21h

    ;load input to di
    mov di,offset buf
    add di,2

    ;//saving length to a variable
    repeat:
    mov al,[di]
    inc count
    cmp al,"."
    je lenchck
    inc di
    jmp repeat
    ;//end saving
    lenchck: 

    dec count  ;as full stop (period) (.) is also included in the count

    stringmatch1:
    mov cx,0  ;reset register
    mov arrayele,0 ;reset variable
    stringmatch: 
    mov di,offset buf  ;loading input to di
    add di,2
                          ;loading array element to si
    mov bx,0
    mov bl,byte ptr words
    mov si,bx             ;end loading array element to si
    mov cl,count
    repe cmpsb
    je equal

    inc arrayele
    inc words    ;next word in the array
    mov bx,0         ;loading it
    mov bl,byte ptr words
    mov si,bx        ;end loading
    cmp arrayele,06d      ;compare to check if all elements have been compared with
    jg wrong

    jmp stringmatch

    wrong:                ;load notequal message
    mov dx,offset mne
    jmp print

    equal:
    mov dx,offset me      ;load equal message
    print:
    mov ah,09h            ;print it    
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch            ;exit the program
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: The dictionary will exceed to nearly 200 words so yes, array is a must, no other way :)

Comment: What's the purpose of `buf db 99,?,99 dup(?)` (compared to just `buf db 99 dup(?)`)?

Comment: @us2012 for input, this must be done, otherwise the program wont take an input

Answer (score 1):

`inc words    ;next word in the array`

No, sorry. You've incremented (what was) the offset of `w0`. You haven't moved to the next word in the array. You want something more like...

```
mov bx, offset words
top:
; get offset of a string
mov si, [bx]
; do your comparison
; start at beginning of input every time
mov di, offset buf + 2 ; don't need a separate operation
mov cl, count ; (are we sure ch is clear?)
repe cmpsb
je found
; no? get next offset in words array
add bx, 2
jmp top
```

In your loop where you look for the '.', what's going to happen if the pesky user doesn't enter a '.'? The second byte in your input buffer (buf + 1), after the interrupt returns, is the count actually entered. It includes the '.' (if there was one) and the Carriage Return (13 or 0Dh) that ended input. You may be able to use this information to rule out obviously incorrect input.

Comment: thanks frank, implemented the carriage return policy, working on the first problem now :)

Comment: One question, My array `words` already has the offsets stored, why would i again offset it to bx as your code states `mov bx,offset words`